# RemoteWebDriver appending '/session' to url

Tags: selenium, web, driver

Using RemoteWebDriver, I am trying to run the following code in a VS2012 MSTest project, inside ClassInitialize method:

```
RemoteWebDriver remote = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost.website/"), DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

I get a WebDriver exception, which shows /session tagged onto the end of the url I have specified:

> {"Unexpected error. \r\n\r\n    \r\n
>   The resource cannot be found.\r\n        \r\n
>   \r\n         body
>   {font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:normal;font-size:
>   .7em;color:black;} \r\n         p
>   {font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top:
>   -5px}\r\n         b {font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top:
>   -5px}\r\n         H1 { font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red
>   }\r\n         H2 {
>   font-family:\"Verdana\";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon
>   }\r\n         pre {font-family:\"Consolas\",\"Lucida
>   Console\",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}\r\n
>   .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}\r\n
>   .version {color: gray;}\r\n         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}\r\n 
>   .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy;
>   cursor:hand; }\r\n         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {\r\n 
>   pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap:
>   break-word; }\r\n         }\r\n         @media screen and (max-width:
>   479px) {\r\n          pre { width: 280px; }\r\n         }\r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n\r\n
>
> ## Server Error in '/MyProject.Web'
>   Application.
>
> \r\n\r\n
>
> ### *The resource cannot be found.*
>
> \r\n\r\n
>   \r\n\r\n             **Description:** HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled
>   correctly.\r\n            
> \r\n\r\n             **Requested
>   URL:** /MyProject.Web/session
> \r\n\r\n
>   \r\n\r\n            **Version
>   Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18033\r\n\r\n            \r\n\r\n
>   \r\n\r\nc__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()\r\n
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult</code>1.End()\r\n
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n 
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()\r\n
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()\r\n
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)\r\n-->"}

Anyone know why it is doing this? This happens know matter the url I point it at.

Comment: And if you go to that URL manually, using your own browser? Your site is broken.

Comment: No its fine visiting manually

Comment: without 'session' it is, at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your error properly (apologies)...

You are using the constructor wrong.

A quick sneek peek into the code shows you are using this constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the RemoteWebDriver class
/// </summary>
/// <param name="remoteAddress">URI containing the address of the WebDriver remote server (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub).</param>
/// <param name="desiredCapabilities">An <see cref="ICapabilities"/> object containing the desired capabilities of the browser.</param>
public RemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
    : this(remoteAddress, desiredCapabilities, RemoteWebDriver.DefaultCommandTimeout)
{
}
```

The URI property you are passing in is the *address of the remote Grid server*. *Not* where you want to go.

Selenium will append the `session` information onto the URL because it would be attempting to create it's own session on the *remote server*.

You sound as though you are running this locally, unless I am misunderstanding you. In which case, either use the encapsulated driver object (so inside of using `RemoteWebDriver` with `DesiredCapabilities.Chrome()` use the `ChromeDriver`) or simply omit the URI property...

```
RemoteWebDriver remote = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

To navigate somewhere *use this*:

```
remote.Navigate().GoToUrl("yourlocalwebsite");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this kind of relates to my other question. I do not want to use ChromeDriver, FirefoxDriver, because I want to be able to test against a host of browsers (locally and on TeamCity) without the browser having to be present on the machine.

Comment: ..if I remove the Uri paramter I get the following error "The path to the chromedriver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property"

Comment: @Tyler, then you are misunderstanding what Selenium is about. You will absolutely positively need the browser installed on the system the tests will run on. The drivers themselves are just bridges to 'talk' to the browsers, not the browsers themselves. You *must* download the ChromeDriver *and* have Chrome installed. Take a step back and read the wiki pages: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver ...and as for TeamCity, it will work fine with the sample code above, again, providing the browsers are installed. (I use TeamCity myself)

Comment: I don't follow you Arran, if I use ChromeDriver then won't that completely go against using RemoteWebDriver? And can't I use DesiredCapabilities.Android, etc. to emulate a browser?

Comment: @Tyler, `ChromeDriver`, `AndroidDriver`, `FirefoxDriver` etc are all facades. If you take a look into the source code, they literally pass down your exact code. Nothing more than that. The various `Driver` classes are there to hide that away. The source code for the ChromeDriver is here... https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver/Chrome/ChromeDriver.cs ...nothing fancy is it? Notice how it inherits from `RemoteWebDriver`?

Comment: Thanks Arran, the documentation is slightly confusing on the Selenium site, can't see the woods for all the trees! To save posting another question - how would I go about testing AndroidDriver, would I need a browser installed for that?

Comment: @Tyler, hopefully that all made sense, let me know if it didn't, As for the AndroidDriver, it's a bit more difficult... http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver should explain it well. You won't need any special browser as such, but you'll need the Android Emulator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24922/discussion-between-tyler-and-arran)

Answer (score 0):

When your are accessing remote browsers, some times they do require User Name and Password. If accidentally you failed to provide same during creating session with RemoteWebDriver() method, you will see error stating "server error ******** /session". So try adding
driver =. new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://:<password/connection key>@.com"))